# A Symmetric bilinear variation for self congruence?

Tags: bilinear-form

--edited--

May I know the **group or condition** that satisfies $$S^T A S = A$$ possibly when $A_{n\times n}$ is symmetric?

Meanwhile, below is an example for $S_{3\times 3}$.

**MATLAB code:**

```
A = [2.9603   1.3855   1.8212    %symmetric
     1.3855   4.7366   1.2824
     1.8212   1.2824   2.653];

S = [-0.29412   -0.35451     0.71379
      0.15026    1.0698      0.18701
      1.15      -0.0036714   0.17226];

S'*A*S     % returns symmetric matrix A as 'ans' below
           % it's off a bit as I intentionally rounded the elements in the 
           % matrices above for the sake of communicating this.

% ans =
%        2.9604       1.3856       1.8212
%        1.3856       4.7367       1.2824
%        1.8212       1.2824        2.653
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "group or condition"? Isn't  $S^T A S = A$ precisely the condition on $S$? Note that if $A$ is too general, namely degenerate, then the set of $S$ satisfying the above condition won't form a group as they won't always be invertible (e.g. $A = 0$ puts no constraint on S).  If $A$ is invertible and of signature (p,q), then by use of the spectral theorem one can show that the group of those $S$ satisfying  $S^TAS = A$ is conjugated to the "orthogonal group in signature (p,q)", $O(p,q)$. But perhaps are you imposing other constraints on $S$, such as being symplectic?

Comment: @JordanPayette, thanks for the insight on spectral theorem.

The conditions are that $A$ is Symmetric, positive definite, and invertible. No, it is not symplectic since simplectic matrices are of the order $2n \times 2n$.

That makes sense now. I do appreciate.

Comment: Of course $S$ can't be symplectic if your matrices are of odd size, but you mentioned symplectic matrices and you chose the symplectic-geometry tag, so that needed precisions. If $A_{n \times n}$ is positive definite, then it only has positive eigenvalues ; by the spectral theorem it's of the form $A = M^TM$ where $M = D^{1/2}Q$ where $D$ is diagonal and formed by the eigenvalues of $A$ and $Q$ is orthogonal. Note that $M$ is invertible, since $A$ is positive definite. Then $\{S : S^T A S = A \} = \{ S : MSM^{-1} \in O(n)\} = M^{-1} O(n) M$.

Comment: @JordanPayette. Thanks for the reply. However, I *honestly* couldn't understand the last part: $\{ S : MSM^{-1} \in O(n)\} = M^{-1} O(n) M$
Can you KINDLY explain with words? Thanks.

Comment: Write $I_n$ for the identity matrix of size n and $O(n) = \{ Q \in M(n, \mathbb{R}) : Q^TQ = I_{n}\}$ for the orthogonal group in dim n. Put differently $Q$ is orthogonal iff $Q^T I_n Q = I_n$. Now by the spectral theorem, for any symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ there are $Q$ orthogonal and $D$ diagonal s.t. $$A = Q^TDQ = Q^T D^{1/2} D^{1/2} Q = (D^{1/2}Q)^T(D^{1/2}Q) = M^TM.$$ Now $S$ satisfies $S^TAS = A$ iff $S^TM^TMS = M^TM$ iff $(M^T)^{-1}S^TM^TMSM^{-1} = I$ iff $MSM^{-1} \in O(n)$ iff  $S = M^{-1}PM$ for some $P$ orthogonal iff $S \in M^{-1}O(n)M := \{M^{-1}RM : R \in O(n)\}$.

Comment: @JordanPayette
 Thank you! Perfectly understood. I do appreciate.